# sybase user defined function - "non deterministic" or "illegal built-in function" error

Tags: function, sybase, user-defined-functions

When trying to create a user-defined functions (UDFs) on sybase 15+, you may get the following error:
"illegal built-in function statement in scalar SQL function"
This is b/c "non deterministic" functions such as getdate(), rand(), newid() are not allowed in UDFs.

Is there a way around this limitation?

Note that I plan answer my own question here.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to create a view such as:

```
create view vGetDate as select getdate() as gtdt
```

Then in the UDF select from that view:

```
create function udf_getdate
returns datetime
as
declare @gd datetime
select @gd=gtdt from vGetDate
return @gd
go
```

Now call the function:

```
select dbo.udf_getdate()
```